# Azure DevOps: can't get secret value from variable group in environment vars

Tags: azure-devops

I use Variable groups in Azure DevOps to store regular and "secret" variables

I used to see both regular and "secret" variables in environment variables on the agent (values of secret values were masked with *****)

Today I found out that secret variables aren't present in agent's env vars anymore

Am I the only person who faced it? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#secret-variables):

> Unlike a normal variable, they are not automatically decrypted into
> environment variables for scripts. You need to explicitly map secret
> variables.

Based on my test , I could also confirm that the secret variables don't appear in the environment variables.

You could use the `$(secretvariable)` format to call the secrets.

If you still want to set the secret variables as the environment variable, you could use the environemt script to achieve it.

For example:

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=variablename;]$(test3)"'
```

**Explaination:**

The `$(test3)` is the secret variable. You could set the secret variable(test3) as the new environment variable(variablename).

Then you could use `$env:variablename` to call the environment variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: many thanks, `echo $(secret_var)` works in inline mode

Answer (score 3):

You have to map the name of a secret to the environment variable before you can use it.

example adapted from [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#reference-secret-variables-in-variable-groups)

```yaml
variables: 
- group: 'my-var-group' # variable group pretend it contains `user` and `token` variables. Token is secret

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # use $Env:USER for user variable
      # use $Env:MY_MAPPED_TOKEN for secret token var that has been mapped in the `env` below
  env:
    MY_MAPPED_TOKEN: $(token) # Maps the secret variable $(token) from my-var-group
```

Comment: yeah, for secret varibles, we need to explicitly export to a env variable to use it in bash/Powershell script.